# How do display a div tag on on the 4th of every month in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i make it display only on 4th of every month and be hidden on the remaining days?

```
<div align="center" style="background-color: #61FF33; padding: 7px 0px; display: none;">
   <marquee style="color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 90%">Today is 4th</marquee>
</div>
```

Comment: no, today is the 19th :(

Comment: Get the current date, test if it's the 4th day : if yes, display it, else do nothing. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Get the current `date` in day format.. compare it with the value 4 and `echo` your `div` if they return true..

```
<?php if (date("j") == 4): ?>
<div align="center" style="background-color: #61FF33; padding: 7px 0px; display: none;">
   <marquee style="color: black; font-size: 20px; width: 90%">Today is 4th</marquee>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: how is that?
haven't used PHP in a while